# Select preferred font in latex

Tags: fonts, symbols, luatex, fontspec

Is there any way to select the prefered font in latex?

For example, If a symbols is missing in the given font file then choose the other font to render the symbol in the document.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf} 
\begin{document} 
    ( AaBb∇αβγ ) \par 
    ( \symbf{AaBb∇αβγ} ) \par 
    ( \symrm{AaBb∇αβγ} ) 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Generally, there is always a fallback font defined for each encoding in traditional TeX. I assume this is true for `fontspec`. However, since there is basically only one encoding for text, at least, it obviously won't work in quite the same way. I assume you're talking about maths, but you don't say whether you are using unicode maths as well or not. Generally, though, a fallback font is just a fallback for the encoding. It does not work on a character-by-character basis. Really need a specific example here.

Comment: i am using unicode math package and i tried to set the math font xits-math.otf and i compile with lualatex it return fatel error.

Comment: here is my tex code :

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\( AaBb∇αβγ \) \par
\( \symbf{AaBb∇αβγ} \) \par
\( \symrm{AaBb∇αβγ} \)
\end{document}

Comment: Note that you can edit your question to add information. For example, if you get a fatal error, please add the text of the error message into your question.